# How can i get this expression of google script?

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script, google-docs

i was trying to get an expression for google script for a google document that i cant get. I want to find all occurences of words that are: "X-X-Xr"
Where "X" is a capital letter or number, "-" it is literally -, and "r" is literally r. I want to find all occurences and then highlight them. The word could be between two blank spaces, or right after a ":"

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
function search4Files() {
  let fs = DriveApp.getFilesByType(MimeType.GOOGLE_DOCS);
  let files = [];
  while(fs.hasNext()) {
    let file = fs.next();
    files.push(file);
  }
  if(files && files.length > 0) {
    let f = files.filter(f => f.getName().match(/([A-Z])-\1-\1r/g)).map(f => [f.getName(),f.getId()]);
    Logger.log(JSON.stringify(f));
  }
}
```

I created a file named X-X-Xr and ran the code.

```
Execution log
10:27:03 AM Notice  Execution started
10:27:04 AM Info    [["X-X-Xr","1WPtB9mdWZsWHEARvHuWdBOld8ay0k9hLTjhkurLe7-E"]]
10:27:06 AM Notice  Execution completed
```

You could post files into a sheet with a setValues if you wish.

Searching for text patterns in files

```
function search4TextPatternsInFiles() {
  let fs = DriveApp.getFilesByType(MimeType.GOOGLE_DOCS);
  let files = [];
  while (fs.hasNext()) {
    let file = fs.next();
    let doc = DocumentApp.openById(file.getId());
    let txt = doc.getBody().getText();
    let m = txt.match(/([A-Z])-\1-\1r/g);
    if(m) {
      let n = file.getName();
      m.forEach(x => files.push([n,x]));
    }
  }
  if (files && files.length > 0) {
    Logger.log(JSON.stringify(files))
  }
}
```

I don't wish to do the highlighting so I left that for you.

Answer (score 0):

Using [Regxr](https://regexr.com/) and [Body.findText()](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/document/body#findText(String)) you should be able to find the strings you want.

[image]

Here is a sample code for Google Doc for the same text shown above.

```
function test() {
  try {
    let doc = DocumentApp.getActiveDocument();
    let body = doc.getBody();
    let find = body.findText("(\\S-){1,}\\Sr");
    let style = {};
    style[DocumentApp.Attribute.FOREGROUND_COLOR] = "#0000FF";  // blue
    while( find ) {
      let element = find.getElement().asText();
      element.setAttributes(find.getStartOffset(),find.getEndOffsetInclusive(),style);
      find = body.findText("(\\S-){1,}\\Sr",find);
    }
  }
  catch(err) {
    console.log(err)
  }
}
```